# USB 2.0 Ports Not Working on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb

I'm currently facing an issue with my USB 2.0 ports on my Ubuntu system and I'm seeking some guidance to resolve it. Here are the details of the problem and the steps I've taken so far:

Issue: My USB 2.0 ports seem to be non-functional. When I plug in any USB 2.0 device (such as a flash drive, keyboard, or mouse) into these ports, nothing happens. The devices don't get recognized, and there's no power or activity. However, my USB 3.0 ports are working perfectly fine.

Steps taken so far:

- Rebooted the system multiple times.
- Tested the USB 2.0 devices on another computer to confirm they're functional.
- Checked for any visible physical damage to the USB ports.
- Ran system updates using sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade.
- Checked the output of lsusb command, but the USB 2.0 devices don't show up.

System Details:

- Ubuntu version: lunar 23.04
- Kernel version: 6.2.0-27

I'm not sure what else to try to get my USB 2.0 ports working again. If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has any suggestions to troubleshoot and fix this problem, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Are there any specific drivers I should check or additional commands I could use to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Please check if your hardware is supported by Linux. Probe your computer and ideally post the public link in your question: https://linux-hardware.org/

Comment: I would boot a *live* system (*I'd opt for something very different to the Ubuntu system you have installed or are currently using*) and see if it works there. If you pull out USB drives that weren't electronically disconnected (via software; ie eject) its possible for the + and - power lines to short which will kill all USB ports permanently; ie. one poor connection can destroy all USB2 ports using the same controller due to power short. Other ports using different hub/circuits (eg. USB3) won't be touched as you describe. If *dead* they won't work on other OSes too (such as a *live* system)